# Is this conflict-serializable? if so find an equivalent serial schedule

Tags: database, serialization, conflict

[image: Schedule]

I'm not sure how to draw precedence graph of this schedule.
Not sure whether to take into consideration the begnning and commit of a transaction or not.

But what i concluded that this schedule can not be serilizabled (there doesn't exist a schedule whos serial equivlent to the schedule above.)

Correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence Graph:

[image]

Yes this schedule is conflict-serializable as by drawing the precedence graph, there is no cycle.

An equivalent serial schedule would be a path where you can visit every node once, which would be `T2 -> T3 -> T1 -> T4` in this case.